# How can I check and add missing rows in a data frame based on an index vector?

Tags: r, tidyr, rbind

I need to add missing rows from "count" based on the "numberclass" that is missing. "numberclass" is the column of the "count" dataset that should go from 1 to 652, but misses some numbers and ends at 645.

To achieve that, I made an index vector that goes from 1 to 652 called c1. 
How can I use rbind to add the missing rows that are missing in "count"? 
Those missing rows should contain the appropriate number in "numberclass" that is missing and a 0 on the column "sum" in the "count" data frame.

visual example

```
count
    numberclass    sum
1        1        3.45
2        2       32.45
3        3       23.11
4        5       21.33
5        6        1.54

c1
   V1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6

finalcount
    numberclass   sum
1        1        3.45
2        2       32.45
3        3       23.11
4        4         0
5        5       21.33
6        6        1.54
```

```
dput(c1)
1:652

> dput(count)
structure(list(numberclass = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 
91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 
105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 
118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 
131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 
144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 
157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 
171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 
184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 
197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 
210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 
223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 
236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 
249, 251, 252, 253, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 
264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 
277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 
290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 
303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 
316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 
329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 
342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 
355, 356, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 
369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 
382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 
396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 
409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 
422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 
435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 
448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 
461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 
474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 
487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 
500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 
513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 
526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 
539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 
554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 
567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 
580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 
593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 
606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 
619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 
632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 
645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652), sum = c(237.750666386555, 
189.540342857143, 351.867604761905, 195.005685714286, 308.574686424686, 
18.2691666666667, 85.6063492063492, 330.872041913642, 12.5832666666667, 
81.3559523809524, 940.085002447968, 38.9222222222222, 67.6095238095238, 
52.4340924675325, 48.9761904761905, 190.221922510823, 67.2384948051948, 
106.311044372294, 50.4888222222222, 40.4883365079365, 146.992341452991, 
43.6190142857143, 133.421034293119, 234.662733903319, 41.3940476190476, 
27.5869769119769, 4.77619047619048, 1.14404345238095, 33.7083333333333, 
44.2833333333333, 22.9526315789474, 21.5833333333333, 10.65, 
2.75, 73.0113858363858, 9.41666666666667, 10.9, 30.3830128205128, 
58.9269230769231, 1.39285714285714, 267.691666666667, 58.0575757575758, 
48.1547008547009, 82.8479908979909, 57.6404761904762, 0.333333333333333, 
15.0952380952381, 62.5674603174603, 155.280158730159, 39.9, 82.6307359307359, 
24.6282467532468, 301.294040989729, 336.528306349206, 19.0833333333333, 
110.152380952381, 151.278584609835, 27.3151515151515, 326.42688974359, 
148.124206349206, 250.934674989716, 791.586193783953, 284.357225111163, 
26.3166666666667, 689.571152020736, 211.649312496276, 143.23373015873, 
104.389479365079, 1977.09488512611, 278.063024283429, 635.353051458803, 
255.639689709121, 182.388611918596, 121.218055555556, 53.5880285714286, 
29.8071514529915, 289.396377133977, 261.427877777778, 13.0333333333333, 
120.082323232323, 26.4499333333333, 118.030555555556, 3.16666666666667, 
3.5, 1.27692307692308, 1327.43098544718, 359.099526103064, 886.03077133796, 
77.9476163059163, 3.7, 204.405522222222, 42.3193805944056, 83.1319512987013, 
32.0430735930736, 100.999933333333, 41.4505205838606, 359.286551817072, 
134.815597663857, 120.851665339892, 68.6170634920635, 120.464757456432, 
98.7313991341991, 138.937179487179, 18.4913941580642, 8.9984237984238, 
238.521621356421, 123.083044733045, 363.372644000444, 39.2380952380952, 
3.16666666666667, 19.6226551226551, 53.5838383838384, 34.581746031746, 
4.95, 131.300949206349, 445.728384935065, 109.100990092656, 364.408721825397, 
61.5416666666667, 222.299498645799, 16.0214285714286, 13.5833333333333, 
35.9928238095238, 522.570385291901, 92.072619047619, 451.015331590632, 
276.63253968254, 61.6666666666667, 56.875, 246.15873015873, 52.5833, 
73.5964119047619, 28.1214646464646, 30.1333333333333, 53.9054945054945, 
206.796237085137, 111.121428571429, 182.169199264787, 59.3175971087736, 
64.3332722832723, 16.9333333333333, 13.9166666666667, 23.3833333333333, 
33.8173992673993, 1.50952380952381, 1.1, 47.9876584126984, 33.6666666666667, 
31.7166666666667, 42.5094738594739, 193.209163059163, 36.8706349206349, 
56.4786214285714, 125.781411481369, 1326.37051628773, 128.802066528312, 
176.118690340834, 124.811656943091, 221.328297720058, 92.4357277483439, 
5.54453781512605, 11.934710550887, 34.1893281555046, 297.559209282097, 
10.45, 15.9714285714286, 0.333333333333333, 404.635647619048, 
1.33333333333333, 423.917088383838, 31.725, 22.2334666666667, 
126.991549902454, 46.2095071428571, 19.9333333333333, 9.41666666666667, 
36.1666666666667, 101.691628950685, 88.0833333333333, 1.08333333333333, 
60.5678571428571, 44.5857142857143, 10.3333333333333, 27.9333333333333, 
59.6450530463688, 33.0823773448773, 15.2018740031898, 139.796428571429, 
302.865200865801, 58.4464285714286, 7.50238095238095, 253.278364368964, 
98.456746031746, 275.551738539239, 224.303773488182, 43.4340004939634, 
14.475, 252.068551587302, 193.944014285714, 97.1103202020202, 
522.762237662338, 152.027922077922, 495.599785289496, 15.45, 
44.4584599224305, 2.63932178932179, 76.913480952381, 18.5944333333333, 
80.5424963924964, 52.8404761904762, 19.602380952381, 21.7789854538307, 
2.09285714285714, 15.6, 57.8281523809524, 114.880233333333, 2.5, 
582.268982688364, 22.8928571428571, 43.5, 71.0449134199134, 13.45, 
71.4832666666667, 382.793654822955, 57.6023587301587, 17.8666666666667, 
134.694036507937, 8.65833333333333, 6.48333333333333, 167.456313131313, 
108.970238095238, 38.0944444444444, 41.4536075036075, 644.437984476377, 
64.2714285714286, 1630.6914617297, 81.8621387218045, 977.944218315018, 
825.631676469739, 76.9720238095238, 161.353968253968, 70.9142857142857, 
122.307142857143, 49.1575757575758, 38.9833333333333, 119.23980017316, 
9.5, 7, 9.03333333333333, 0.285714285714286, 2.81558441558442, 
34.3352130179203, 423.489491888615, 26.7138582972583, 20.2610666666667, 
70.2504356560596, 84.3197993439266, 133.202467136288, 452.717995233655, 
320.773420116725, 209.525511634406, 641.329055345934, 9.29166666666667, 
20.0666666666667, 23.4825757575758, 42.336926961927, 21.5083333333333, 
48.472619047619, 5.68452380952381, 3.61666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
22.6410952702853, 2596.19741576659, 3701.15679179432, 458.475674942574, 
0.177777777777778, 236.511739558926, 178.846204916721, 554.69148345371, 
109.069139904866, 27.9428571428571, 865.353323873349, 1315.57171181985, 
4.94494734487734, 367.766031285642, 519.099162156913, 703.569199879477, 
570.161782712288, 55.7592247797747, 424.061781409081, 4.14444444444444, 
7.85, 1.5, 203.543559424236, 417.414520853467, 118.026934176934, 
13.8930333333333, 5.3, 195.214038429218, 2, 125.901590928837, 
20.183510972172, 174.23474402697, 115.783354224877, 20.9589971153889, 
64.2541744390332, 30.1928142135642, 653.283386817422, 45.4998949579832, 
2.28333333333333, 35.7234848484849, 13.4766233766234, 1, 1, 151.923361772117, 
466.496416114588, 241.639269088134, 208.697684171547, 37.1753432142857, 
32.7720180265813, 28.2666666666667, 32.9353202020202, 29.3107466063348, 
52.1338661616162, 92.2408604474645, 143.825094880675, 146.094892496393, 
185.56378660516, 229.435060026582, 35.8161587301587, 358.75152088854, 
9.54144989396568, 100.579542891096, 48.5654928571429, 182.120363315018, 
92.411123015873, 213.978268831169, 30.4477001960784, 133.023283627484, 
1.48156826833297, 8.58333333333333, 4.44443333333333, 38.2468253968254, 
56.047481038406, 67.3214285714286, 123.833316666667, 72.7440476190476, 
4.04166666666667, 15.0999833333333, 66.4499333333333, 200.083454172494, 
6.04285714285714, 160.691602741703, 6.19924242424242, 1.33333333333333, 
108.082979449584, 106.752280952381, 14.5075757575758, 17.3920634920635, 
131.341230952381, 44.2768897435897, 313.758134920635, 2.16666666666667, 
16.6477124183007, 4.75, 23.7767065934066, 114.554377815518, 67.8246376228347, 
127.12717047619, 8.01590909090909, 62.9999458874459, 24.5385558774559, 
25.4267800865801, 64.9809956302521, 26.8670829004329, 144.936510045837, 
18.2714285714286, 181.673313930514, 6.37619047619048, 122.4944, 
163.107067798868, 62.2391525974026, 100.821861471861, 66.6090659340659, 
151.295802741703, 227.115548340548, 161.469246031746, 20.8428571428571, 
98.9682406349206, 84.2357142857143, 63.5107142857143, 587.042635340803, 
291.116304438862, 217.717193917194, 314.73560018413, 198.123701298701, 
236.697900710401, 410.192568542569, 118.817857142857, 143.350727050727, 
81.387055999556, 43.8719696969697, 203.429180541681, 517.788687667888, 
61.2261904761905, 382.272785934066, 75.7309523809524, 112.349503174603, 
22.7539682539683, 31.7878787878788, 71.6388888888889, 116.672591197691, 
31.4399816686581, 139.147260092848, 38.9365079365079, 142.327696091318, 
73.9474025974026, 353.130164019063, 49.7790027560675, 247.005519209059, 
98.4489704073704, 22.8163324675325, 49.0166666666667, 398.237265694185, 
20.0119047619048, 127.929437229437, 29.906746031746, 11.4833333333333, 
29.5477994227994, 17.2627344877345, 1, 275.39396990232, 155.285052380952, 
191.24167394958, 17.5547619047619, 32.6397907647908, 48.0516145404303, 
20.0202991341991, 296.087292678082, 6.05553333333333, 6.30952380952381, 
550.020158730159, 398.502413950429, 697.700455175612, 342.769086313686, 
100.248412698413, 578.569767384318, 323.557284593185, 578.870478870574, 
799.803117448702, 66.4497474747475, 52.7964285714286, 28.2440476190476, 
1, 9.15, 0.333333333333333, 101.279396149946, 20.4504329004329, 
2, 0.342857142857143, 11.0416666666667, 114.264102564103, 148.394093406593, 
17.3285625923784, 10.2605680868839, 109.262121733822, 5.68568095238095, 
4.91666666666667, 27.8404512154512, 95.3755683538683, 134.882303769841, 
61.262513966589, 16.5333333333333, 64.6593323051948, 37.6535103785104, 
42.0317820956821, 17.3730092063492, 81.8735937673438, 44.7111111111111, 
17.4607142857143, 70.0927904761905, 148.696792063492, 170.374507625708, 
185.520274170274, 177.809072871573, 86.3721112221112, 176.200008488178, 
15.1166666666667, 136.109471067821, 48.0101062250443, 166.262856565657, 
148.329752057299, 151.820306375846, 4.18642884892885, 13.65, 
17.5384920634921, 158.262582783883, 255.417342568543, 29.2134920634921, 
197.809798534799, 29.85, 16.9095238095238, 20.8333333333333, 
113.602744444444, 44.002380952381, 36.0333333333333, 318.15949047619, 
116.7, 9.73333333333333, 459.457291197691, 200.920720879121, 
314.905574729437, 468.928687626263, 127.85367965368, 34.46829004329, 
127.564573784059, 168.830957864358, 276.134640779221, 201.892396392496, 
1946.09400347577, 201.03562536075, 0.54047619047619, 782.099165160003, 
425.714983516484, 89.7872682539683, 146.385452539683, 10.6666666666667, 
1025.68925909923, 116.007914285714, 276.85727701204, 289.008666233766, 
251.763574012009, 83.7539682539683, 348.782956092124, 241.232478499278, 
35.9951548451548, 23.8844904761905, 16.75, 15.6583166666667, 
23.4777777777778, 5.83333333333333, 262.787474045562, 285.537711241699, 
63.2683473389356, 66.3647186147186, 2, 8.83323333333333, 751.311316139416, 
20.0833333333333, 3.48333333333333, 313.547763557495, 24.6952380952381, 
2.33333333333333, 60.6101524475524, 111.872585714286, 52.7153693528694, 
181.421808730159, 86.6900043290043, 223.108003141303, 16.0825757575758, 
304.663375396825, 48.2595238095238, 53.0539682539683, 117.610714285714, 
3.1, 1.83333333333333, 305.834008148714, 197.169349200473, 0.5, 
8, 33.7777777777778, 1.2, 5.58333333333333, 42.6051282051282, 
144.887301587302, 65.7499666666667, 963.598530853141, 217.737908305747, 
19.827380952381, 3.775, 229.018578571429, 7.19166666666667, 186.860334126984, 
9.33333333333333, 0.75, 1, 43.8273809523809, 62.2753634920635, 
301.048005944774, 89.4083452763611, 374.762004736842, 166.820046453546, 
1058.5261360623, 872.182726540127, 54.4082666666667, 1227.53727689429, 
321.227890629965, 148.721916971917, 277.273484848485, 897.280942113442, 
226.137230929597, 72.7005952380952, 140.310317460317, 317.511606180094, 
209.189406410256, 104.605501434676, 437.805596256685, 273.362576312576, 
8.47222222222222, 227.129921804748, 0.943686868686869, 67.7638777888778, 
20.4856893106893, 99.1611000111, 166.165773015873, 82.3694444444444, 
227.211077777778, 72.4857142857143, 461.993158401598, 78.8, 210.535976984127, 
428.665560794761, 35.797619047619, 133.786890638528, 20.4904761904762, 
577.348705757576, 404.170196392496, 1101.04344335286, 270.924821327561, 
196.366666666667, 5.83333333333333, 81.6839466089466, 516.43132186441, 
2.33333333333333, 10.9095238095238, 54.1369047619048, 48.2956349206349, 
676.496237656507, 137.799728238428, 14.4768149941046, 355.509695218997, 
422.28376567026, 213.912283405959, 177.353159198024, 14.0459013125763
)), row.names = c(NA, -645L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution with the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)
count <- as.data.frame(count)
count <- count %>% complete(numberclass = full_seq(numberclass, period = 1),fill=list(sum=0))
```

No need for an extra index vector.